# identity from sql insert via jdbctemplate

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

Is it possible to get the @@identity from the SQL insert on a Spring jdbc template call? If so, how?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The `JDBCTemplate.update` method is overloaded to take an object called a GeneratedKeyHolder which you can use to retrieve the autogenerated key.  For example (code taken from [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jdbc.html#jdbc-auto-genereted-keys)):

```
final String INSERT_SQL = "insert into my_test (name) values(?)";
final String name = "Rob";
KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
jdbcTemplate.update(
    new PreparedStatementCreator() {
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            PreparedStatement ps =
                connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL, new String[] {"id"});
            ps.setString(1, name);
            return ps;
        }
    },
    keyHolder);
// keyHolder.getKey() now contains the generated key
```

Comment: That would be the "one liner" I am looking for here. Nice. Sad thing is I saw the link but glossed past it due to this: "part of the JDBC 3.0 standard". (I don't think we use JDBC 3.0, but I also don't think this is relevant).

Comment: It getting a real one liner in Java 8 with lambdas \m/

Comment: What if the generated key is not a number, but a string?

Comment: in case of using NEWID, which is a hash (string) how would you return it?

Comment: KeyHolder has not only getKey(), but also getKeys() and getKeyList() methods, returning key values as Objects.

Comment: Does the table (my_test) has to have IDENTITY property? without it, I am getting null exception.

Answer (score 52):

How about `SimpleJdbcInsert.executeAndReturnKey`? It takes two forms, depending on the input:

### [(1) The input is a `Map`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcInsert.html#executeAndReturnKey-java.util.Map-)

> `public java.lang.Number executeAndReturnKey(java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?> args)`
>
> **Description copied from interface: [`SimpleJdbcInsertOperations`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcInsertOperations.html#executeAndReturnKey-java.util.Map-)**
>
> Execute the insert using the values passed in and return the generated key.
>   This requires that the name of the columns with auto generated keys have been specified. This method will always return a `KeyHolder` but the caller must verify that it actually contains the generated keys.
>
> **Specified by:**
>
> [`executeAndReturnKey`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcInsertOperations.html#executeAndReturnKey-java.util.Map-) in interface [`SimpleJdbcInsertOperations`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcInsertOperations.html)
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> `args - Map containing column names and corresponding value`
>
> **Returns:**
>
> `the generated key value`

### [(2) The input is a `SqlParameterSource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcInsert.html#executeAndReturnKey-org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource-)

> `public java.lang.Number executeAndReturnKey(`[`SqlParameterSource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/SqlParameterSource.html)`parameterSource)`
>
> **Description copied from interface: [`SimpleJdbcInsertOperations`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcInsertOperations.html#executeAndReturnKey-org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource-)**
>
> Execute the insert using the values passed in and return the generated key.
>   This requires that the name of the columns with auto generated keys have been specified. This method will always return a `KeyHolder` but the caller must verify that it actually contains the generated keys.
>
> **Specified by:**
>
> [`executeAndReturnKey`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcInsertOperations.html#executeAndReturnKey-java.util.Map-) in interface [`SimpleJdbcInsertOperations`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcInsertOperations.html)
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> `parameterSource - SqlParameterSource containing values to use for insert`
>
> **Returns:**
>
> the generated key value.

Comment: Wow, I didn't really know about that class - kinda neat. Thanks. +1

Comment: I like this version more than version with PreparedStatementCreator.

Answer (score 28):

Adding detailed notes/sample code to todd.pierzina answer

```
jdbcInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(jdbcTemplate);
        jdbcInsert.withTableName("TABLE_NAME").usingGeneratedKeyColumns(
                "Primary_key");
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("Column_NAME1", bean.getval1());
        parameters.put("Column_NAME2", bean.getval2());
        // execute insert
        Number key = jdbcInsert.executeAndReturnKey(new MapSqlParameterSource(
                parameters));
           // convert Number to Int using ((Number) key).intValue()
            return ((Number) key).intValue();
```

Comment: I'm facing this exception :
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: The getGeneratedKeys feature is not supported by this database

Comment: @Az.MaYo - Your issue could be related to JDBC driver version.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is a "one-liner" but this seems to do the trick (for MSSQL at least):

```
// -- call this after the insert query...
this._jdbcTemplate.queryForInt( "select @@identity" );
```

Decent article [here](http://www.zabada.com/technology/Wiki.jsp?page=SpringAndJDBC).

Comment: Page not found with the link.

Comment: For SQL Server, @@identity returns the last id generated on any table in the database in the current session.  So for example if your insert causes a trigger to fire that also generates a new identity in some table, you'll get that value.  In a majority of cases you never want to use @@identity.