# How can I get auto increment values in batch update query (Java,MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, spring-jdbc, batch-updates

I am using Spring-Jdbc template(first timer) to create MySql repository. I have tables that use AutoIncrement columns as primary key.

I wonder if there a way to get newly generated Ids (autoInc) with each successful batch create statement?

Any pointers or sample would be a great help.

Thanks
Panks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the insert ID in JDBC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`getGeneratedKeys()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29) method from your `Statement` or `PreparedStatement` object to identify the new auto generated values. Iterate the returned `ResultSet` object to get the newly generated key values in the order of batch statements.

This call may throw [`java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLFeatureNotSupportedException.html) if the JDBC driver, that you are using, does not support this method.

**Sample code snippet**:

```
String sql_insert =  
    "insert into my_table ( non_auto_incrmnt_fld_names_,_separated ) " +  
                 " values ( record1 ), ( record2 )"; // append as many as required  
...  
int rowsAffected = stmtObject.executeUpdate( sql_insert, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS );  
ResultSet rs = stmtObject.getGeneratedKeys();  

//******************************************************  
rs.last();  
int rows = rs.getRow();  
System.out.println( "Generated keys count: " + rows );  
int currentRow = 1;  
rs.beforeFirst();  
//******************************************************/  

while( rs.next() ) {  
    System.out.println( /**/( currentRow++ ) + " = " + /**/rs.getInt( 1 ) );  
} // while rs
```

Comment: Thanks Ravinder, That solution goes with raw jdbc. I am working with spring jdbctemplates. I found one solution for it using spring jdbc- [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665846/identity-from-sql-insert-via-jdbctemplate     But I am looking for a solution for batch update.