# Spring 3.2 retrieving auto-generated keys using SimpleJdbcInsert

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-data

As per [Spring 3.2 Data access docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-simple-jdbc-insert-2), SimpleJdbcInsert can be use to retrieve auto generated keys. But, I cannot override  the final method setDataSource from JdbcDaoSupport in the code below:

```
public class LoginDAOImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport implements LoginDAO {

    // Cannot override the final method from JdbcDaoSupport
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    }
```

JdbcDaoSupport class is not extended in the Spring 3.2 doc. So, I have 2 questions:

1. How to use SimpleJdbcInsert to retrieve auto-generated keys while extending JdbcDaoSupport class?
2. If I do not extend JdbcDaoSupport then what shall be the code changes in the configuration file and dao class. Please find below current configuration and dao code:

configuration file:

```
    <bean id="loginDao" class="com.vikas.dao.LoginDAO"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />
```

relevant doa code:

```
getJdbcTemplate().update(...);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variation of `SimpleJDBCInsert` which takes `JdbcTemplate` as the constructor argument.

`SimpleJdbcInsert simpleJdbcInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(getJdbcTemplate());`

This way there is no need to try and get hold of the datasource directly.

Answer (score 0):

After removing JdbcDaoSupport, I am able to retrieve auto-generated keys using SimpleJdbcInsert by following changes:

configuration file:

```
<bean id="loginDao" class="com.vikas.dao.LoginDAOImpl"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />
```

DAO class:

```
public class LoginDAOImpl implements LoginDAO {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private SimpleJdbcInsert insertPerson;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {

        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        insertPerson = new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource).withTableName("PERSON")
                .usingGeneratedKeyColumns("PERSON_ID");
    }

    @Override
    public void addPerson(Person person) {

        SqlParameterSource parameters = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(
                person);
        Number newId = insertPerson.executeAndReturnKey(parameters);

        String sql = "INSERT INTO PERSON_ROLE (PERSON_ID, ROLE) VALUES (?, ?)";

        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, newId.longValue(), person.getPersonRole().getRole());
    }

}
```

I am still looking for a way to use SimpleJdbcInsert while extending JdbcDaoSupport.

Answer (score -1):

auto generated key's are generated on insert, not on update

Comment: I am passing insert query to getJdbcTemplate().update("INSERT INTO PERSON ...", ...); Also there is no getJdbcTemplate().insert method. However, my question is regarding changes required to use SimpleJdbcInsert in existing JdbcDaoSupport implementation to retrieve auto generated keys.

Comment: i am sorry bro. i find a link may be it can help you see the accepted answer .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665846/identity-from-sql-insert-via-jdbctemplate