# How to insert with JdbcTemplate returning autogenerated id?

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I want to make use of spring `JdbcTemplate` to insert a line and return the id autogenerated by the `mysql` db.

Without spring I'd do similar as follows:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (id, filename, timestamp) VALUES (NULL, ?, NOW())";
Statement st = con.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

st.setString("test.csv");
st.executeUpdate();
st.getGeneratedKeys().next().getLong(1);
```

Question: how could I achive the same with `JdbcTemplate`?

Answer (score 1):

In short its

```
 Number key = jdbcInsert.executeAndReturnKey(new MapSqlParameterSource(
                parameters));
```

You can check my answer in [identity from sql insert via jdbctemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665846/identity-from-sql-insert-via-jdbctemplate/21623957#21623957)

Comment: Where would I add my sql statement there?

Comment: Can you please check the thread I shared, you can find other ways to achieve this including the SQL one. If you want to stick to SQL statement, then I guess you can use the KeyHolder with update statement or call jdbcTemplate.queryForInt() after insert statement has been called.